# Writing list items in one line

Tags: python

Given a list (could be more than one), I would like to write the items in the list in one line separated by spaces. What is the best way to do it?

For example,

Input:

```
sentence1=["I", "like", "yellow", "flowers"]
sentence2=["I", "like", "blue", "sky"]
```

Output:

```
I like yellow flowers
I like blue sky
```

Comment: join each list using space? and then join each resultant string using space as well? - `str.join()` .

Comment: Besides.. you missed a `"` in the input..

Comment: `" ".join(sentence1)` ?

Comment: What are those negative votes for?

Comment: @cerebrou I didn't downvote your question but I can guess that people downvoted because it's pretty basic and easy to find in a google search

Comment: Sure, but whoever downvoted and put the answer hoping for upvotes to that "obvious question" is hypocritical.

Answer (score 4):

This will output the sentences, each on their own line

```
 print(" ".join(sentence1))

 print(" ".join(sentence2))
```

Be sure to fix the syntax errors in the list definitions, though.

Answer (score 2):

Here you go :)

```
print(' '.join(sentence1))
print(' '.join(sentence2))
```

> The join() is a string method which returns a string concatenated with the elements of an iterable. Syntax: `string.join(iterable)`

Answer (score 1):

Unpack the list using `*`

```
sentence1=["I", "like", "yellow", "flowers"]
sentence2=["I", "like", "blue", "sky"]
print(*sentence1)
print(*sentence2)
```

Answer (score 0):

This function will help you:

```
    def join(*args):
            result = list()
            for i in args:
                result.extend(i)
            return ' '.join(result)
sentence1=["I", "like", "yellow", "flowers"]
sentence2=["I", "like", "blue", "sky"]
sentence3=["I", "like", "green", "grass"]
join(sentence1, sentence2, sentence3)
```

Answer (score 0):

In Python3 you can use

```
print(*mylist)
```

In Python 2

> 

```
for i in range(len(mylist)):
         print mylist[i],
```